# moment().isBefore is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to compare current time with a certain date like so:

`const expireTime = "2020-01-10T11:51:47+08:00";`

`console.log(moment().isBefore(expireTime));`

However even if current time (which is `moment()`) is past `expireTime`.. the above expression still returns `true`. Anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: You can't use curly quotes around JavaScript strings. Is that really in your code?

Comment: You also have two quotes at the beginning, a curly quote followed by a double quote.

Comment: Nope it's not. Just typo here in post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the string into a moment, like this:

```
const expireTime = "2020-01-10T11:51:47+08:00”;

console.log(moment().isBefore(moment(expireTime)));
```